# Telemetry Data is not uploaded to Azure Application Insights

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights

I have developed one java application which sends the custom metrics data to Azure Application Insights as

```
TelemetryClient azureNbClient =  new TelemetryClient();
MetricTelemetry metric = new MetricTelemetry();
metric.metric.setName("name");
metric.setValue("value");
azureNbClient.trackMetric(metric);
```

But the data is not uploaded in Azure. 
What are settings required to send the Data to Azure. I am not getting any exceptions also while executing it.

Could you please let me know the configurations required? As per the document provided by Azure following ports needs to be open. What exactly do we need to do for this settings? 
Make sure your firewall allows your application to send telemetry to these ports:

- dc.services.visualstudio.com:443
- dc.services.visualstudio.com:80
- f5.services.visualstudio.com:443
- f5.services.visualstudio.com:80

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the required settings for sending telemetry to Application Insights, the required setup and configuration information are detailed in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-get-started/).

Assuming that you have followed through the steps in the article and still cannot see telemetry in Application Insights, then please try the following:

- Try sending the metric telemetry using the simple option:

  TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

  telemetry.trackMetric("Name", value);
- Turn on logging to the IDE console window, by adding an <SDKLogger /> element under the root node in the ApplicationInsights.xml file (in the resources folder in your project), and check for entries prefaced with [Error].
- As for the ports, in your firewall, you might have to open TCP ports 80 and 443 for outgoing traffic to the addresses and ports you mentioned above. This is to ensure that the machine on which your application is running has internet connectivity to the Application Insights service on Azure.

Hope this helps,

Harel